# Fusion Chart Invalid Data error

Tags: jsp, fusioncharts

I am using fusion chart in jsp pages.
When I am storing my data.xml files in resources folder of war file, fusion chart is rendering the data properly. But,
When I put those data files in local directory, say **"C:/dataFiles/"**. I am getting error as **Invalid Data**. When I right click and play the chart on chrome it is showing **No data to Display error**.

Can any one please sort this out for me?
I am using 
fusionChartVar.setDataURL("C:/dataFiles/data.xml"); method.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using relative path location to load XML file instead of absolute path?

Comment: Relative path, like if we are storing these files in project war file i.e. if we deployed them on server then, it is working fine.
But we need to give other path like c:/tempDir/data/. In this case it is not working.